# How to read and write large std::vector<std::vector<float>> to file in C++

Tags: c++, lookup-tables

In the constructor of my program I am generating a very large lookup table of 2048 * 2048 floats using nested `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

The lookup table is always the same each time, so I'd like to write this table to a file to save recalculating it.

What is the best way to achieve this? Is it best to write the values to a big header, or is it wiser to save a binary copy of the object?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

If it is of any conceqence, perhaps it's related to the time take to allocate the memory which is being done with the following pattern:

```cpp
dataStructure.resize(numberOfRows);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
     dataStructure[i].resize(numberOfColumns);
```

Where datastructure is a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`

Comment: How long does it take to generate? Is loading it from disk faster?

Comment: So 16MB of data? That's not large at all but I would not put it into the source code.

Comment: I do not know the best way to write it to and from disk. That's really the thrust of my question. Perhaps it's the way the memory is being allocated. It's being allocated like so: (see edit in question).

Comment: Any chance to let the compiler perform the calculation with a constexpr? Or perform the calculation offline and initialize a constexpr with the computed values.

Comment: If memory allocation/deallocation is a concern, you can try using `reserve` instead of`resize` to allocate memory without initializing new elements, and then `push_back` to add the new elements without allocating extra memory. You can also `std::move` your sub-vectors into the main vector one when reading.

Comment: "best" is subjective. Fastest I/O? Most readable code? Least effort to develop? Most flexible if you need to radically change it in the future? Without any other knowledge of your situation, I would say just do something that works and is understandable. Chances are it'll be good enough for what you need. If you are concerned about performance or such, then test it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case has been to optimise the lookup table generation. I was doing much, much more work than was required, and now load times are practically instant.

For those in the future looking at this thread with a similar problem, there is great general advice in the commments.

Thanks to the attention of all who contributed!

Comment: Maybe you should consider summarizing that "general advice in the comments" in your answer and then, possibly, making your answer a [Community WIki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/616624).